# Rails: User list with more information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey,
I'm trying to create a user/member list for a site. Every user listed should have additional information stored in the database like online status, age etc.
I know how you can list users with

```
render @users
```

but that just gives me a list of names.
How do I manage to let's say create a table and each row is a user with additional information about this user?

Answer (score 0):

You need create ourself the html in view of you user index

Comment: yea I know, I have an index_item partial where I created the row for every user... but how do I let rails go through the users model and fill those rows for every single user?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your action name is 'index'...

```
def index
  @users = get_your_users_wherever

  # Don't call render, just let it fall through to your template.
  # Typically templates are named after the action (index in this case).
end
```

In your template

```
<table>
<%- @users.each do |user| %->
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
  </tr>
<%- end -%>
</table>
```